# cross domain google analytics tracking when using fancybox iframes

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, fancybox

I have a site that uses google analytics and is that uses a number of domains. I was asked to add cross domain tracking by doing this:

1) Add an async tracker

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21602333-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

2) Add the following code to all links that go to one of the other domains.

```
 <a href="http://www.domain-aanvraag.nl[rest van de link]" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.domain.com']); return false;">Go!</a>)
```

The _link option  does the following according to google:

> This method works in conjunction with the _setDomainName() and
>   _setAllowLinker() methods to enable cross-domain user tracking. The _link() method passes the GATC cookies from this site to another via URL parameters (HTTP GET). It also changes the document.location and
>   redirects the user to the new URL.

Ok. This all works fine for normal outgoing links.

Here's the problem. I have a form in which the user can select one of two radio buttons and after selecting one he hits a submit button. If the first radio button is selected a fancybox popup is opened with an iframe in it pointing to the a page on another domain. If the second radio button is opened the current window is redirected to another page on this domain.

I only want to do the `_gaq_push(['_link', ...])` thingy when the user selects the first option and clicks the button.

So I have two issues with this:

1. Where should I place the onclick.
2. How do I use this code using fancybox? It seems to always set the document.location of the main screen and not of the iframe in my fancybox, resulting in a complete refresh of my screen.

Here's a stripped down working example of my code so far: https://www.domain.com/test/analytics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged a little deeper and the underlying problem here is that I am trying to create a cross domain tracking link to another domain in another iframe instead of a whole new window (the iframe is created by fancybox). So instead of using _link I should use _getLinkerUrl as described here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#trackingIFrames

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using jquery for the fancybox you can use this.

give the radio button a id of clickme and then place this script after the radiobutton

```
<input id="clickedme" type="radio" name="option" value="1" data-link="http://ato.xximo-aanvraag.nl/Home/Step1?companytype=zzp">

<script>
$("#clickme").bind("click", function(event){
  _gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.xximo.com']);
  alert('click recorded, you can remove me') // remove if needed
});
</script>

//hoop dat het is wat je zoekt ;)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this after the weekend. I think that the _link method will force a full page refresh though. :/

Comment: You can change the _gaq.push to whatever you want _trackEvent, _trackPageview etc etc.